# Creating a Gem that adds a rails form helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm creating a gem to add a new helper method for rails forms.  My gem is a single file

```
lib/rails_json_field.rb
```

that looks like this:

```
require 'action_view/helpers'
require 'action_view/context'
require 'securerandom'

module ActionView
  module Helpers
    class FormBuilder
      include ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper
      include ActionView::Helpers::JavaScriptHelper
      include ActionView::Context

      def json_field_tag(method, options = {})
        #function code here
      end
    end
  end
end

ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_view) do
  include ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
end
```

However when I use the method like so:

```
= f.json_field_tag(:some_method)
```

I receive the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `json_field_tag' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007ffa84ab52a8>)
```

How do I make the method available on `ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching, I found a different gem that adds a FormBuilder method.  I used their repo as a guide to structure my own.  For others with this questions, you can view my repo and their repo here respectively:

https://github.com/dyeje/rails_json_field

https://github.com/Brantron/john_hancock

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the following class:

```
RailsJsonField::ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
```

You meant to monkeypatch the following class:

```
ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
```

That's why the error message is telling you the method is undefined; you have defined it within a class within your custom module, not within the specified class:

```
undefined method `json_field_tag' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
```

It's only defined in `RailsJsonField::ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder`, so you get the above error.

If you want to properly monkeypatch the original code then you should look at the original code to ensure *your* code looks like [*their* code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb):

```
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    class FormBuilder
      def json_field_tag(method, options = {})
        # function code here
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It would be better to define this as an initializer in your Rails app, e.g., in `config/initializers/json_field_tag.rb`. Once you have the code working as a simple patch, then you can focus on developing it into a standalone gem that enhances `ActionView`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm able to get it working as an initializer, but then the same code doesn't work in the gem (gets the error I included in the question).  Do you have any ideas on how I could debug the issue or the proper way to initialize the code in the gem?  I've updated the code in the question.